# DoctrineORM : Error while inserting data into a table which has foreign key attribute

Tags: mysql, database, symfony, doctrine

I have the following database structure given by
[image]

The `"subcat_id"` column in the `"Course"` table points to the `"id"` column in the `"sub_category"` table.
The `"instructort_id"` column in the `"Course"` table points to the `"id"` column in the `"user"` table.

I want to insert data in the "course" table. I am using Symfony2 framework with Doctrine as the database library. When I try to insert data into the course table using the following statements:

```
        $newCourse=new \FrontEndBundle\Entity\Course;
        $newCourse->setSubcat($data['subcat']);
        $newCourse->setName($data['coursename']);
        $newCourse->setInstructor($instructorId);
        $newCourse->setDescription($data['description']);

        $em->persist($newCourse);
        $em->flush();
```

, I get an error(`$newCourse` is an object of the Course Entity class)

Error shown is displayed below:
[image]

I think the error relates to foreign key issues. Can anyone help me on how can I insert data
In the course table correctly? 
Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: First check you dependency key in tables. If you want insert to table with forgein key you must first insert to priority table.

Comment: I have values inserted into the priority tables.

Comment: while setting your subCat you are passing a string instead of a SubCategory object

Comment: I even converted the datatype of those variables to int, but I still get an error.

Comment: "string given" text in the error image is replaced by "int given"

Comment: try `$subCat = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('FrontEndBundle:SubCategory')->find($data['subcat']);` and then `$newCourse->setSubcat($subCat);`

Comment: i post it as answer if it has been useful :-)

Comment: Yes..you may do so..@ponciste

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this problem is because you are passing a id, which is not a SubCategory object to your setter in the SubCategory entity

so, you have to retrieve you SubCategory object first, then set it to the Course entity

try this way

```
$subCat = $this->getDoctrine()
               ->getRepository('FrontEndBundle:SubCategory')
               ->find($data['s‌​ubcat']);
```

and then

```
$newCourse->setSubcat($subCat);
```